# PEM PPK file access removal

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, passwords

I have been dealing with someone with regards to accessing and making changes on my website.
I have shared with him my pem key file, and all passwords.

What can I do to restrict him from accessing my website/files before he does something to sabotage my company, as i am leaving his services and moving on..

I know you going to say change all passwords but what about the .pem file connecting via SSH that doesn't require a password?

Thank you.

Platform
Ubuntu
ec2
AWS
Moodle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The an SSH connection is initiated, Linux will look in the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. If the public keypair in that file matches the private keypair used when requesting the SSH connection, then the connection will be permitted.

Therefore, you should **remove the public key from the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file**.

If that is the only keypair, then make sure you also insert the public key for a keypair that you have, so that you can still SSH into the instance.

Better yet, **do not use SSH to connect to instances**. Instead, use [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html), which uses IAM to grant access to instances. This way, you can simply remove somebody from IAM and they can no longer access the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to EC2 -> Instance -> select your instance -> Network & Security -> Key Pairs and then delete the key you have used before and create a new key pair for the instance. He wont be able to access the server with the old key pair.

Comment: are you sure I was told pem file is assigned to that instance on creation? if you loose it you screwed?

Comment: Yes, please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Comment: or do it via Linux terminal https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-keypairs.html